# Wordpress rename post name within plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Within my Wordpress plugin I am trying to display the **post name** dynamically. For example, [www.site.com/item/123/My_nice_item](http://www.site.com/item/123/My_nice_item) will load the post/page item with ID 123, and within this I want to display 'My nice item' within the `<h1>` tags.

For the title I already managed this with `add_rewrite_rule`.